# Angular: I have to store api response of object form to use further. Please let me know convenient way to store that response

Tags: javascript, angular

**Angular: I have to store API response which is in object format to use further and to minimize further API calls. Please let me know a convenient way to store that response.**

My Code Snippet (Service File Code):

```
getList(){
  ....
  ....
  let url = '####';
  return this.http.get(url);
  ....
  ....
}
```

Above function getting call multiple times, **I have to store API response to use further** or to minimize API calls further. please let me know your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the local storage if you want save the response for a long time or even if the page refreshed, or you can use the memory (but you will lose the data when the service re-initialized. To use the the memory add an array as variable into the service, then in you function getList check that variable if it's not empty return it else call your API and save the response in the variable before returning it

Comment: I tried with local & session storage with.. JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse(). But when I restore using JSON.parse(), then it's not remaining in the same format.

Comment: you have "return this.http.get(url);" wich return a subject you will need to use the local storage in the subscriber.

Can you put the full code with the issue so we can look into it